# text issue in reading portuguese language rss and storing in database

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I am trying to read an `rss` feed which data is written in Portuguese language.

**What I want**

1. I read `rss`
2. Storing title and description in variables
3. Then storing those variables in MYSQL using insert query

But when data inserting in database then some texts are in bad format

for example the actual title in rss feed is

```
 problema com funções
```

but when store in my database then it store as following

```
 problema com fun&ccedil;&otilde;es
```

I am using following code

```
 $title=trim(htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

Same happening with description too. also I want to remove html tags also from description.

Anybody can help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Those two strings are the same,

Comment: here's a [very extensive post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) on encoding. Basically it can go wrong in many places but once your setup is correct you're OK for most (if not all) languages...

Comment: the stackflow conver my bad char string to normal string. this is what i want to do. convert portueges bad char to norma